# Re-adding Deleted Code as Part of a Merge

Tags: git, git-merge

I have branch A on which, among other change, a line of code was deleted.

Branch A was merged into demo. Said line of code need to be added back into demo.

So on branch A, I added the code back in and commit the change.
But when I merge branch A back into demo, the line of code is not added back into demo.

I believe this has to do with the fact that Branch A has no record of the line ever being changed so it won't reintroduce the deleted code. 
How do I re-add the deleted code to demo as part of merging branch A?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe should not occur.  Adding the files to the branch and re-merging is a correct procedure.

Git doesn't know or care that you're "re-introducing" code; to git files are added, and that itself is a change.  So the fact that files with the same name and content were earlier deleted, or that they hadn't been otherwise modified on the branch, or anything else... doesn't matter.  You're introducing a whole bunch of concepts that don't really exist, and complicating your view of what git does.

You had

```
O --- x --- x --- x <--(master)
 \
  A --- B --- C --- D <--(branch)
```

and maybe `A` deleted `foo/*`.  You merged

```
O --- x -- x --- x -- M <--(master)
 \                   /
  A --- B --- C --- D <--(branch)
```

and now the deletion of `foo/*` was carried into `M`.  To fix this you add a commit to `branch`

```
O --- x -- x --- x -- M <--(master)
 \                   /
  A --- B --- C --- D --- E <--(branch)
```

and `E` creates files at `foo/*`.  If you merge this to `master`:

```
O --- x -- x --- x -- M --- M2 <--(master)
 \                   /     /
  A --- B --- C --- D --- E <--(branch)
```

the merge base is `D`.  Only `D`, `E`, and `M` are examined to produce `M2`.  Because `M` doesn't do anything at `foo/*`, while `E` creates files at `foo/*`, `M2` will get the files.  The history before `D` doesn't matter.

This is documented behavior which has worked in numerous tests for countless users, so I would advise that you re-check your work and make sure you re-added and merged in the way you describe.